# How to rewrite the protected/private route using TypeScript and React-Router 4, 5 or 6?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, typescript2.0

I was trying to create a `<PrivateRoute>` as describe in the react-router [documents](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) using TypeScript. Can anyone help me out?

**The privateRoute in react-router document:**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
      <Component {...props}/>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location }
   }}/>
  )
 )}/>
)
```

**Below is my TypeScript version(it won't work) :**

```
const PrivateRoute = (theProps: { path: string, component: React.SFC<RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined> | React.ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any> | undefined> }) => {
    return <Route path={theProps.path} render={props => (
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
            <React.Component {...theProps} /> <!-- **** It will raise error *** -->
        ) : (
                <Redirect to={{
                    pathname: '/',
                    state: { from: props.location }
                }} />
            )
    )} />
}
```

The `<React.Component {...thisProps} />` is not right. The error is: NodeInvocationException: inst.render is not a function
TypeError: inst.render is not a function

Answer (score 147, accepted):

### Original Answer (2017)

*(Updated answers below)*

Probably the error has to do with the typing and the implicit return in rendering. When you fix this you get ultimately to something like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}: any) => {
    const routeComponent = (props: any) => (
        isAuthenticated
            ? React.createElement(component, props)
            : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login'}}/>
    );
    return <Route {...rest} render={routeComponent}/>;
};
```

This component can be used like this:

```
<PrivateRoute
    path='/private'
    isAuthenticated={this.props.state.session.isAuthenticated}
    component={PrivateContainer}
/>
```

There are a few draw backs with the solution above. One of the is that you lose type safety.

Probably extending the `Route` component is the better idea.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route, RouteProps} from 'react-router';

export interface ProtectedRouteProps extends RouteProps {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    authenticationPath: string;
}

export class ProtectedRoute extends Route<ProtectedRouteProps> {
    public render() {
        let redirectPath: string = '';
        if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
            redirectPath = this.props.authenticationPath;
        }

        if (redirectPath) {
            const renderComponent = () => (<Redirect to={{pathname: redirectPath}}/>);
            return <Route {...this.props} component={renderComponent} render={undefined}/>;
        } else {
            return <Route {...this.props}/>;
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use the component like this:

```
const defaultProtectedRouteProps: ProtectedRouteProps = {
    isAuthenticated: this.props.state.session.isAuthenticated,
    authenticationPath: '/login',
};

<ProtectedRoute
    {...defaultProtectedRouteProps}
    exact={true}
    path='/'
    component={ProtectedContainer}
/>
```

### Update (Nov 2019)

If you prefer to write functional components you can do it in a very similar manner. This also works with React Router 5:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

export interface ProtectedRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  isAllowed: boolean;
  restrictedPath: string;
  authenticationPath: string;
}

export const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = props => {
  let redirectPath = '';
  if (!props.isAuthenticated) {
    redirectPath = props.authenticationPath;
  }
  if (props.isAuthenticated && !props.isAllowed) {
    redirectPath = props.restrictedPath;
  }

  if (redirectPath) {
    const renderComponent = () => <Redirect to={{ pathname: redirectPath }} />;
    return <Route {...props} component={renderComponent} render={undefined} />;
  } else {
    return <Route {...props} />;
  }
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

### Update (Dec 2019)

If you want to redirect a user to the path the user wanted to access first, you need to remember the path, so you can redirect after successful authentication. The following answer will guide you through that:

[Redirecting a user to the page they requested after successful authentication with react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422159/redirecting-a-user-to-the-page-they-requested-after-successful-authentication-wi/59423442#59423442)

### Update (Mar 2021)

The solution above is a bit outdated. The ProtectedRoute component can simply be written as follows:

```
import { Redirect, Route, RouteProps } from 'react-router';

export type ProtectedRouteProps = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  authenticationPath: string;
} & RouteProps;

export default function ProtectedRoute({isAuthenticated, authenticationPath, ...routeProps}: ProtectedRouteProps) {
  if(isAuthenticated) {
    return <Route {...routeProps} />;
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: authenticationPath }} />;
  }
};
```

If you use React Router V6 you need to replace `Redirect` with `Navigate`. A full example with redirection to the originally requested page can be found here:

- [React Router 5 example](https://github.com/openscript/react-router-private-protected-routes/tree/react-router-5)
- [React Router 6 example](https://github.com/openscript/react-router-private-protected-routes/tree/react-router-6)

### Update (Jan 2022)

As children of `<Routes>` need to be `<Route>` elements the `<ProtectedRoute>` can be changed to:

```js
export type ProtectedRouteProps = {
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  authenticationPath: string;
  outlet: JSX.Element;
};

export default function ProtectedRoute({isAuthenticated, authenticationPath, outlet}: ProtectedRouteProps) {
  if(isAuthenticated) {
    return outlet;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to={{ pathname: authenticationPath }} />;
  }
};
```

`<ProtectedRoute>` can now be applied like follows:

```
const defaultProtectedRouteProps: Omit<ProtectedRouteProps, 'outlet'> = {
  isAuthenticated: !!sessionContext.isAuthenticated,
  authenticationPath: '/login',
};

return (
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
      <Route path='dashboard' element={<ProtectedRoute {...defaultProtectedRouteProps} outlet={<Dashboard />} />} />
      <Route path='protected' element={<ProtectedRoute {...defaultProtectedRouteProps} outlet={<Protected />} />} />
      <Route path='nested' element={<ProtectedRoute {...defaultProtectedRouteProps} outlet={<Layout />} />}>
        <Route path='one' element={<Protected />} />
        <Route path='two' element={<Protected />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
);
```

I've also updated the [React Router 6 example](https://github.com/openscript/react-router-private-protected-routes/tree/react-router-6). By now there is even an official guide about this: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth

Comment: what if I connect ProtectedRoute to redux to get the IsAuthenticated property ? would it cause performance issues ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. There is just one if/else more compared to the original use of `Route`.

Comment: Brilliant solution @Robin.
:)
I'll add my 2 cents here:
1. ProtectedRouteProps need not have isAuthenticated because it highly depends on this.props.state. Which means each component will have to have that info. 

Instead Devs can use some sort of GlobalState / GlobalStore or Mobx based observable variable to detect isAuthenticated(or is, props will not get passed to

Comment: @Piyush: I disagree with your idea to omit the `isAuthenticated` from the props, because the component won't be reusable anymore. I suggest to create some kind of Router container component, where you set up all the routes and bind the state.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @Robin

Comment: react strongly recommends to compose rather than inherit

Comment: @JoeyBaruch I agree. See `Update (Nov 2019)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found it very useful. Just have a quick short question, why do you put a `render={undefined}` on your redirect component? I am a little confused, thanks!

Comment: @ysong4: The reason is, that we are spreading `this.props` which can contain a `render` prop and we want to get rid of this in that case.

Comment: @Robin, sadly this solution is broken in the latest v6, perhaps a bug?

Comment: [ProtectedRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment> :(

Comment: @kevinob You are right. I've updated the solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can still use the SFC form, which I find a little cleaner. Just mix in any props you need with the `RouteProps`:

```
const PrivateRoute: React.SFC<RouteProps> = ({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}: {
  component: React.ComponentType<RouteProps>;
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated 
        ? <Component {...props} /> 
        : <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
  />
);
```

Comment: `component` should be type `React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>>` rather than `React.ComponentType<RouteProps>`, no?

Answer (score 10):

For react-router-dom (v6.0.2) , you can use the following code for your **PrivateRoute component**:

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useAppSelector } from 'app/hooks';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

interface PropType {
    component: React.FC;
}

const PrivateRoute: FC<PropType> = ({ component: Component }) => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useAppSelector(state => state.auth);

    if (isAuthenticated) return <Component />;
    return <Navigate to='/login' />;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

To use inside your **App.tsx**, you can use it as follows:

```
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path='/home' element={<PrivateRoute component={HomePage} />} />
            <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
```

Answer (score 7):

My PrivateRoute

```
import React from 'react'
import {Redirect, Route, RouteProps} from 'react-router'

export interface IPrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  isAuth: boolean // is authenticate route
  redirectPath: string // redirect path if don't authenticate route
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<IPrivateRouteProps> = (props) => {
   return props.isAuth ? (
    <Route {...props} component={props.component} render={undefined} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to={{pathname: props.redirectPath}} />
  )
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Using

```
<PrivateRoute isAuth={false} redirectPath="/login" path="/t1">
  <Pages.Profile /> your`s protected page
</PrivateRoute>
```

Answer (score 5):

This really helped me

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

interface IProps {
    exact?: boolean;
    path: string;
    component: React.ComponentType<any>;
}

const LoggedOutRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    ...otherProps
}: IProps) => (
    <>
        <header>Logged Out Header</header>
        <Route
            render={otherProps => (
                <>
                    <Component {...otherProps} />
                </>
            )}
        />
        <footer>Logged Out Footer</footer>
    </>
);

export default LoggedOutRoute;
```

Source: https://medium.com/octopus-wealth/authenticated-routing-with-react-react-router-redux-typescript-677ed49d4bd6

Answer (score 4):

We can write as below without providing very explicit and exact types or interfaces in tsx. Just write like -{ component: Component, ...rest }: any- as type and we are done.

```
  export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) {
      const { currentUser } = useAuth();

      return (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) => {
            return currentUser ? (
              <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
              <Redirect to="/login" />
            );
          }}
        ></Route>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using v6 of React-router-dom we handle the protected route in this format

Setting up the Auth protection component

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../state/hooks";

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element }> = ({ children }) => {
  const {user} = <Your-State-Provider>// Redux/Context or even in-memory user
  const location = useLocation();
  return !user.isAuthenticated ? (
    <Navigate to={"/login"} state={{ from: location }} replace />
  ) : (
    children
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

In this Basically The user authentication state will be checked then against that condition we user the `<Navigate/>` to redirect back to login page. We get the current location and pass it to the `Navigate` so that we redirect the user to the intended page after login automatically. We restructure the `children` props and render the `children` if the user is authenticated. The advantage of this is that we'll just wrap the element we want to render with the `<ProtectedRoute>{children}</ProtectedRoute>`.

#### Consuming the Protected Route

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/ProtectedRoute/ProtectedRoute";//Your protected route
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login";
import MainPage from "./pages/MainPage/MainPage";


const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        <nav>
          <Link to="/admin" />
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute>
                <MainPage />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Because `react-router-dom v6` allows nesting of components in the route now we just wrap the component we want to protect with the `ProtectedRoute` eg

```
 <Route path="/" element={ <ProtectedRoute><Your-Protected-page /></ProtectedRoute>}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick code snippet:

```
export function PrivateRoute () {
  const { auth } = useAuth()

  if (!auth) return <Navigate to="login" />

  return <Outlet />
}
```

use

```
  <Route Component={PrivateRoute}>
    <Route path="/" Component={MyPage} />
  </Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems since react-router-dom 6.0.0-beta.4 for me only that worked:

```
App.tsx

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Navigate, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

interface Props {}
export const App: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
    const isAuthenticated = true;
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path={`/`} element={isAuthenticated ? <AuthenticatedPage /> : <Navigate to={`/auth`} />} />
                <Route path={`/auth`} element={<AuthenticationPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8033

Answer (score 1):

Just to add what worked for me:

```
interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  component: React.FC<RouteProps>;
  path: string;
}

export default function PrivateRoute({
  component: Component,
  path,
}: PrivateRouteProps) {
  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      render={(props) =>
        localStorage.getItem('user') ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

and can be used like this:

```
<PrivateRoute path="/user/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick code snippet:

> PrivateRote.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useLogin} from 'hooks'

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  component: any
}

export const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const { component: Component, ...rest } = props
  const { isLogin} = useLogin() //true/false or something else

  return account ? <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
}
```

> usage in App.tsx

```
<Router>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/faq" component={Faq} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is clean and simple.

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";

import { RoutePaths } from "./RoutePaths";

interface Props extends RouteProps {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
}

const AuthRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    if (!Component) {
        return null;
    }

    const { isLoggedIn } = rest;

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) =>
                isLoggedIn ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: RoutePaths.Auth,
                            /**
                             * For redirecting after login.
                             */
                            state: { from: props.location },
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default AuthRoute;
```