# NextJS: How to redirect a user to the page they requested after successful authentication with?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have seen examples of this with `react-router` (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422159/redirecting-a-user-to-the-page-they-requested-after-successful-authentication-wi)), but any ideas on how this can be done in NextJS, on both client side and server side redirects? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-paper-28h1f) i have used react context and i aso redirect on server and client side